# How to set alert dialog box in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-studio-3.0

How to set alert dialog box in android java?

How to set alert dialog box in android java?

Comment: Don't repeat your question three times. If Stack Overflow was complaining that your question was too short, then that's a hint that you should improve the question. Check out [ask] and [mre] for more information. You may also want to take the [tour] and check out the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal alert Dialog would look something like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title of the alert dialog");
builder.setMessage("Message to be displayed in the alert dialog");
builder.setPositiveButton("Positive Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Code to be executed when the positive button is clicked
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Negative Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Code to be executed when the negative button is clicked
    }
});

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

You can customize this more. Please look into the AlertDialog class in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs)